# Inequality in non-decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

Let $a, b$ be two sequences of real numbers such that $a_1 \le a_2 \le \dots \le a_n$ and $b_1 \le b_2 \le \dots \le b_n$. Prove (or disprove) that

$$\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{b_i}\right) \le \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_ib_i}\right)$$

Now obviously, I have no idea from where to even start attacking this monster. I tried Cauchy-Schwarz (square roots of $a_i$ and $b_i$), and by using AM-GM on the left side, but realized that they are not necessarily non-negative.

Comment: This is Chebyshev's inequality. Hint: use rearrangement to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a standard Inequality and there are numerous proofs if I am not mistaken. I'll give you two options. One I'll give you a hint and you can pursue a solution on your own which will help you. But if you have a million exercises following this and using this inequality then you can choose to just refer this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) which contains a simple proof.

***Hint:*** Consider the sum $$ \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n(a_i - a_j)(b_i - b_j) $$

Since we know that $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$ are monotonically increasing and since either $i \le j$ or $ i \gt j$ the signs of the two facotrs $ (a_i - a_j) $ and $ (b_i - b_j)$ will always be the same and hence the iterated sum will be non-negative. Now you have an inequality. Expand and continue.

Comment: Splendid. I am absolutely embarrassed for being unable to get any results from google on this inequality. Thanks!